# Attach object to an area

Tags: objects, physics, constraints, properties

I have created a Cube with a hole in it and a Cylinder which fits into the hole, but the diameter of the hole is bigger than of the Cylinder.
So I want to move the Cylinder without passing through the Cube in the area of that hole. 
Is there a way to attach the Cylinder to that area, so that it cannot move outside of it? St that it can't pass the line where normally the surface of the Cube would be, if I haven't booleaned it with a Sphere.
[image: Cube with hole and the Cylinder]

Greetings W.Zayde

Comment: Are you trying to make like this http://pasteall.org/pic/5f3f8526f7d21e4fd89e44e35084f455

Comment: No, I am trying to attach the Cyilder to the hole of the Cube, so that when I animate it, the Cyilnder can only move around in the specific area. I don't want the Cylinder to pass through the Cube like, there must be a physics to avoid that and I don't want the Cylinder and the cube to be one object that was booleaned together.